# Help me find an adapter USA --> Israel

Tags: power

I just bought a [cat feeder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NOLD18) from the united states, and brought it to Israel. Israel has 220V power sockets, and the device (that came with the timer below) doesn't fit, obviously.

The problem is I don't know which adapter to buy. I guess we have the standard European sockets, but the first converter I bought simply wouldn't fit because it had room for only two pins, and the timer in the picture has a third pin.

Can someone help me find which adapter I need in order to plug the timer in the picture to Israel (= European) power output?

[alt text http://sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-sjc1/hs336.snc3/29405_360690984158_690184158_3248527_3179436_n.jpg](http://sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-sjc1/hs336.snc3/29405_360690984158_690184158_3248527_3179436_n.jpg)

Comment: This is a consumer question, not about electrical engineering.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think you have three problems.

1. The timer and cat feeder are not rated for wide voltage operation. Both parts are only designed for 120 volt operation. Simply plugging it in to a 220 volt outlet using a plug adapter will result in a dead timer and cat feeder. I'm not sure if you knew this, but I'm not assuming anything. At a minimum, you will need a voltage converter of some sort.
2. The round bottom pin is the ground terminal of the socket. You could probably bypass it, although if your sockets have a ground, its best to connect it.
3. The timer probably uses the ac frequency as a time standard. I'm guessing your power is 50 Hz, so the timer would run slower. If this is the case, that's going to be hard to fix.

I would recommend getting a lamp timer in your country, and then using a voltage converter to run the cat feeder. In a pinch, removing the ground pin will make things fit, but it's less safe.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah Israel is not a standard European socket it's an H type (SI 32 Israel), European plugs only have two pins and they're not angled, the cat feeder looks like it has a B type mains plug (NEMA 5-15 USA 3 pin)

You can find all the different types on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_power_around_the_world)

The thing about travel plug adaptors is it's best to buy them in the country you intend to use them in, because they are generally cheaper and easier to find, try your local airport or tourist shop.

If not here's one on [Ebay](http://cgi.ebay.com/USA-UK-Euro-AUS-Israel-Travel-Adapter-AC-Power-Plug-/260594120059?cmd=ViewItem&pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cac9eb57b)

Comment: I'd take heed of W5VO's answer too - Point number 1 is a really important, you don't want to blow the thing up with 220V!